# highlight column differences

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I need to Highlight columns that have different values.
If the value on `$b['nama']` and `$c['nama']` is not the same i need to highlight the `<tr>`. I wanted the system admin to easily see which of the field is having different values so the admin can decide to approve user edit request or to reject the request.

```html
<?php
        error_reporting(0);
        $b = $data->row_array();
        $c = $data2->row_array();
        ?>
  <!-- Begin Page Content -->
  <div class="container-fluid">



    <!-- DataTales Example -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">

      <div class="card-header py-3">
        <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">User requested changes</h6>
      </div>

      <div class="card-body">

        <table id="tabel" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 75%">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Variable</th>
              <th>Current data</th>
              <th>Requested changes</th>

            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>

            <tr>
              <td>Nama</td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $b['nama']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $c['nama']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>NIP Baru</td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $b['nipBaru']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $c['nipBaru']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>NIP lama</td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $b['nipLama']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $c['nipLama']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gelar depan</td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $b['gelarDepan']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $c['gelarDepan']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Gelar belakang</td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $b['gelarBelakang']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $c['gelarBelakang']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Tempat lahir</td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $b['tempatLahir']; ?>
              </td>
              <td>
                <?php echo $c['tempatLahir']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>


          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:10%"><span class="icon-cursor"></span> Approve</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:10%"><span class="icon-cursor"></span> Reject</button>




      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing something with `if ($b['nama'] != $c['nama'])...`

Answer (score 0):

Check if those two values are different and apply a class to the row

```
<tr<?php if ($b['nama'] != $c['nama']) { echo ' class="highlight"'; } ?>>
    <td>Nama</td>
    <td>
       <?php echo $b['nama']; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $c['nama']; ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

then use `CSS` to highlight the cells

```
.highlight td {
   background: yellowgreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code
you can change the bgcolor value or you can create css class and inside of if you echo the class='my_class'

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$b = $data->row_array();
$c = $data2->row_array();
?>
<!-- Begin Page Content -->
<div class="container-fluid">



    <!-- DataTales Example -->
    <div class="card shadow mb-4">

        <div class="card-header py-3">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">User requested changes</h6>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">

            <table id="tabel" class="table table-bordered table-striped" style="width: 75%">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Variable</th>
                    <th>Current data</th>
                    <th>Requested changes</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                <tr <?php if ($b['nama'] != $c['nama']){echo "bgcolor='#FF0000'";}  ?>>
                    <td>Nama</td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $b['nama']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $c['nama']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr <?php if ($b['nipBaru'] != $c['nipBaru']){echo "bgcolor='#FF0000'";}  ?> >
                    <td>NIP Baru</td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $b['nipBaru']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $c['nipBaru']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr <?php if ($b['nipBaru'] != $c['nipBaru']){echo "bgcolor='#FF0000'";}  ?> >
                    <td>NIP lama</td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $b['nipLama']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $c['nipLama']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr <?php if ($b['gelarDepan'] != $c['gelarDepan']){echo "bgcolor='#FF0000'";}  ?> >
                    <td>Gelar depan</td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $b['gelarDepan']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $c['gelarDepan']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr <?php if ($b['gelarBelakang'] != $c['gelarBelakang']){echo "bgcolor='#FF0000'";}  ?> >
                    <td>Gelar belakang</td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $b['gelarBelakang']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $c['gelarBelakang']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr <?php if ($b['tempatLahir'] != $c['tempatLahir']){echo "bgcolor='#FF0000'";}  ?> >
                    <td>Tempat lahir</td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $b['tempatLahir']; ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo $c['tempatLahir']; ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>


                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:10%"><span class="icon-cursor"></span> Approve</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="width:10%"><span class="icon-cursor"></span> Reject</button>




        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a class named 'same' and 'different'. Then in php check if the values are same and echo the class property based on being same or different.
**php**

```
            <tr>
              <td>Nama</td>
              <td class="<?php echo ($b['nama'] == $c['nama'])? 'same': 'different'; ">
                <?php echo $b['nama']; ?>
              </td>
              <td class="<?php echo ($b['nama'] == $c['nama'])? 'same': 'different'; ">
                <?php echo $c['nama']; ?>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

In Styles

```
.same{
        color:green;
    }
    .different{
        color:red;
    }
```

We have used ternary operator to figure out if the variables are same or not. 
https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-use-the-php-ternary-operator

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to be using Bootstrap, you could just apply an already defined style to the cells to highlight the difference. For instance:

```
        <tr>
          <td>Nama</td>
          <td class="<?php echo ($b['nama'] == $c['nama'])? 'bg-success': 'bg-danger'; ">
            <?php echo $b['nama']; ?>
          </td>
          <td class="bg-<?php echo ($b['nama'] == $c['nama'])? 'bg-success': 'bg-danger'; ">
            <?php echo $c['nama']; ?>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

By doing this, if `$b['nama']` and `$c['nama']` are different, the cells would have an near-red background and if they are equal, they'd have a near-green background. If you'd like to only highlight differences (in order to make the screen less overwhelming, just replace the `'bg-success'` with `''` so the equal cells don't get styled